# How to compile pre-standard c++ in command line?

Tags: c++, compiler-construction

Here is an example of the type of code i want to compile in command line in windows-

```
#include <iostream.h>

void main()
{
    cout << "Hello World!";
}
```

Comment: ...make it standard C++?

Comment: I cant do that since the would not be mine...I just have to compile and execute it

Comment: You really should learn and use C++11 and use a recent compiler (e.g. [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)...); your old C++ is almost as deprecated as PL/1

Comment: if you have the source to compile, you can change it.

Comment: @DaanTimmer That didn't exist pre-standard.

Comment: I known c++ 11. There are no Namespaces in pre-standard c++. Actually i am making an automated compiler, which compiles in the langauge chosen by the user.

Comment: @Basile, we still use a PL/1 variant at my current workplace, one of the reasons it's only my current workplace for a couple of weeks :-)

Comment: If the C++ is generated, stick to some standard C++ and require a standard conforming C++ compiler. The market for pre-standard generated C++ is probably tiny.

Comment: oh my god.... the dude just asked how to compile legacy code, and he gets a lecture about how wonderful is c++11

Answer (score 4):

You need to find a compiler that conforms to the pre-standard language.

You could go looking for one, such as the Turbo C++ found in the museum of Borland/InPrise/Enchilada <sup>(a)</sup> (or whatever they call themselves nowadays), or you could join us in the 21st century and write standards-compliant code:

```
#include <iostream>
int main() {
    std::cout << "Hello World!\n";
    return 0;
}
```

---

<sup>(a)</sup> Apparently at http://edn.embarcadero.com/ though I can't get it to load at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

You can write your own preprocessor with sed!

Put this in `modernise.sed`:

```
1 s/^/namespace std {}\
using namespace std;\
\
/
s/^void main/int main/
s/iostream\.h/iostream/
```

Then:

```
sed -f modernise.sed t.cpp | g++ -xc++ -
```

Comment: How can i insert a new line after `using namespace std;`?

Comment: And of course, the `using namespace std;` would have to _follow_ the includes of the standard library.  You can use `sed` for small things (I've done so in the past), but if you want to be systematic, you'll need something more complex.  (I use Python for a lot of this sort of stuff.)

Comment: @Sid: I edited my answer to insert a newline after `using namespace std` and add some other niceties (see my next comment).

Comment: @JamesKanze: I've updated my code to insert `namespace std {}` at the very top to avoid warnings from Clang (GCC gave no such warning, and even in Clang it's not an error how it was, but I agree something needed to be done).  I agree that Python is a more sophisticated tool, but someone compiling such old code may not even have a reasonable version of Python available.  And besides, doing it in sed is probably easier so long as the number of changes required doesn't get too out of control.  If I wanted to do something really fancy I'd use GCC-XML or the Clang equivalent.

Comment: @JohnZwinck `sed` would be my tool of choice as long as everything is on a line by line basis.  I'd use `python` here because I'd want to maintain state, inserting the `using namespace std;` after the last include, for example.